# I'm getting a completely unexpected result from if-statements?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class bankcounter {
  public static void main(String []args) {
  int numchecks;
  double totalfeeforchecks;
  double totalfee;
  double totalbasecharge;
  double bankfee;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.printf("Enter in the amount of checks you wish to use: ");
  numchecks = in.nextInt();
  totalbasecharge = 20.00;
  bankfee = 10.00;
  totalfeeforchecks = 0;
  if(numchecks > 0 && numchecks < 20)
        {
        totalfeeforchecks += (numchecks * .10);
        }
  else 
        {
        totalfeeforchecks += (19 * .10);
        numchecks -= 19;
        }
        if(numchecks > 0 && numchecks <= 20) 
            {
            totalfeeforchecks += (numchecks * .08);
            }
        else
            {
            totalfeeforchecks += (20 * .08);
            numchecks -= 20;
            }
            if(numchecks > 0 && numchecks <= 20)
                {
                totalfeeforchecks += (numchecks * .06);
                }
            else
                {
                totalfeeforchecks += (20 * .06);
                numchecks -= 20;
                }
                if(numchecks > 0 && numchecks <= 20)
                    {
                    totalfeeforchecks += (20 * .04);
                    numchecks -= 20;
                    }
                else
                    {
                    totalfeeforchecks += (numchecks * .04); 
                    }
totalfee = totalfeeforchecks + totalbasecharge + bankfee;
System.out.printf("Based on our check fee schedule: .10 cents for less than 20 checks :: .08 cents for 20-39 checks :: .06 cents for 40 to 59 checks :: .04 cents each for 60 or more checks\n\nYour charges are as follows: \nTotal fee = %.2f \n\tTotal base charge = \t%.2f\n\tTotal bank fee = \t%.2f\n\tTotal fee for checks = \t%.2f", totalfee, totalbasecharge, bankfee, totalfeeforchecks);
```

So, if I input 9 for numchecks, the total fee for checks should only be .90, not 2.96. Are my if statements not working? I thought if I put 9 for numchecks, it should only be run past the first condition, since I nested the rest of them... help?

Comment: Why do you have things indented the way they are?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be trivially debugged by stepping through it with a debugger.

Comment: You did **not** nest your `if` statements.

Comment: You've indented them, but you haven't nested them. This isn't Python: to nest conditions you have to actually put them inside the braces.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the tools in your IDE, such as the formatter and debugger.  With these tools you would see you have this line four times

```
if(numchecks > 0 && numchecks <= 20)
```

And this is true four times, so in stead of the `if` not working it is in fact working more than you thought.

This means you are running

```
totalfeeforchecks += (numchecks * .10); // 0.9
totalfeeforchecks += (numchecks * .08); // 0.72
totalfeeforchecks += (numchecks * .06); // 0.54
totalfeeforchecks += (20 * .04); // 0.8
// total is 2.96
```

Comment: But I thought that that was nested under the else statement..

Comment: @AllisonStafford - simply indenting your statements does not make them nested.

Comment: @AllisonStafford only the statement or block after the `else` is nested under the `else` not every statement after it.

Comment: @AllisonStafford just because you add spaces doesn't mean that the compiler changes its behaviour. This isn't Python...

Comment: Oh, thanks. Python is my first language, I'm sorry.

Comment: @AllisonStafford for java in particular , the tools in your IDE will make your life easier. I suggest using the formatter, the debugger and code completion  routinely.

Answer (score 1):

Let me fix that indentation for you, without actually changing the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class bankcounter {
  public static void main(String []args) {
  int numchecks;
  double totalfeeforchecks;
  double totalfee;
  double totalbasecharge;
  double bankfee;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.printf("Enter in the amount of checks you wish to use: ");
  numchecks = in.nextInt();
  totalbasecharge = 20.00;
  bankfee = 10.00;
  totalfeeforchecks = 0;

  if(numchecks > 0 && numchecks < 20)
  {
        totalfeeforchecks += (numchecks * .10);
  }
  else 
  {
        totalfeeforchecks += (19 * .10);
        numchecks -= 19;
  }

  if(numchecks > 0 && numchecks <= 20) 
  {
        totalfeeforchecks += (numchecks * .08);
  }
  else
  {
        totalfeeforchecks += (20 * .08);
        numchecks -= 20;
  }

  if(numchecks > 0 && numchecks <= 20)
  {
        totalfeeforchecks += (numchecks * .06);
  }
  else
  {
        totalfeeforchecks += (20 * .06);
        numchecks -= 20;
  }

  if(numchecks > 0 && numchecks <= 20)
  {
        totalfeeforchecks += (20 * .04);
        numchecks -= 20;
  }
  else
  {
        totalfeeforchecks += (numchecks * .04); 
  }

  totalfee = totalfeeforchecks + totalbasecharge + bankfee;
```

and the reason should now be obvious.